# get every step value with easing plugging

Tags: jquery, easing

Is there a way to get every step value with easing functions? Currenntly my code looks like this:

```
       $(background_div).animate({ "width": "some_width" }, { easing: "easeInOutCirc" });
```

it doesnt allow me to be notifyed about every width value incrementation/decrementation.

Comment: jquery animate has a step function callback, start by reading the DOC

Comment: but it executes only twice - at the start and at the end

Comment: This is maybe due to type effect you are using, could you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: Please refer this url. might be its help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121255/toggle-div-with-easing

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mrEL6/

Comment: Instead of `alert`, use `console.log` and you will see it triggers more than twice.

Comment: yes,this works.But I still missunderstanding why alerts were not executed.Thanks for your usefull note