# Secondary Navigation/Menu bar that pushes web content down on hover of primary navigation button

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a simple navigation menu that when you click on one of the buttons, a secondary menu pops up below, but pushes the content below down with a sliding action.

There will be 6 buttons in the primary menu, spanning the width of the containing div at 960px. Then when you hover on "Products" only, every other primary button will go to a new page, this should open a secondary nav that spans 2 lines. Each button is 159px.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="menu"> 
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">About Us</a></li>
            <li id="products"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="suppliers.html">Our Suppliers</a></li>
            <li><a href="findus.html">Find Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="deliveries.html">Deliveries</a></li>
            <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>

     <div id="subMenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="winesandspirits.html">Wine &amp; Spirits</a></li>
            <li><a href="beersandciders.html">Beer &amp; Ciders</a></li>
            <li><a href="otherdrinks.html">Other Drinks</a></li>
            <li><a href="cheese.html">Cheese</a></li>
            <li><a href="meatsandpate.html">Meat &amp; Pate</a></li>
            <li><a href="vegetables.html">Vegetables</a></li>
            <li><a href="drystores.html">Dry Stores</a></li>
            <li><a href="honey.html">Honey &amp; Preserves</a></li>
            <li><a href="oliveoilandvinegar.html">Olive Oil &amp; Vinegar</a></li>
            <li><a href="sweetthings.html">Sweet Things</a></li>
            <li><a href="hampers.html">Hampers</a></li>
            <li><a href="accessories.html">Accessories</a></li>  
        </ul>
    </div>

     </div>
```

And my CSS:

```
#menu a {
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-style: italic;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12.5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding:0;
    margin: 0
}
#menu a:hover {
    color: #cff;
}
#menu {
    background: #689169;
    height:35px;
    width: 960px;
    transition:height 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition:height 0.2s;
}
#menu:hover {
    height: 105px;
}
#menu ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    list-style:none;
}
#menu ul li {
    float: left;
}
#menu ul li a {
    width: 159px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    /*padding: 10px; padding-right: 30px; padding-left: 30px;*/
    margin: 0;
    background: #689169;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px solid #666;
    display:block;
}
#subMenu {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-top: 34px;
    width: 700px;
    height: 600px;
}
#subMenu ul {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
#subMenu ul li {
    clear: both;
    border-right: 1px solid #666
}
#subMenu ul li a {
    background: none;
    border: none;
}
#subMenu ul li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
#outset {
    width: 700px; height: 300px;
    background: #900;    
}
```

Here's my JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Jfdvr/1/ - please help!

Many thanks,

Matt

Comment: You add css the same way as HTML an JavaScript

Comment: Thanks Jaques, i missed the ctrl+k thing!

Answer (score 0):

I would look into jQuery easing to bounce out a div with css display: hidden; So when a link is clicked the hidden div will ease out and then set a click anywhere else to revert to hidden

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for your reply, but i'm unsure of the correct search terms for this, i've been looking all morning with no joy. Perhaps you could help me with an example of some code or a link to a page that might help. Thanks for your time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121255/toggle-div-with-easing does this help?

Comment: @Adam'Sacki'Sackfield - This is not quite right, i'm after a hover state. so that when you hover on "Products" (see my jsfiddle) the secondary menu slides and pushes everything below it downwards.

Comment: you can change the jquery event handler to hover rather than click to do the animation you require

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/u7GX8/1004/ - I've changed the state to hover, but i need the the "some text here" box to be hidden and the when you hover on the button it appears.

Comment: your almost there at this to the css and it will work mate.            #mypage-info1 {
    display: none;
}

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks bud, i'm gonna give this a go at formatting to my website, i'll let you know how i get on!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CrHxL/6/ - Could you please have a look at my code, i cant see where im going wrong, many thanks!

Comment: Hey Adam, did you get a chance to look at this? I've been trying but i'm not getting anywhere, i'd really appreciate the help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry been mad busy will have a look this evening and get back to you mate!

Comment: Thanks so much mate, really appreciate that! good luck with the work.

Comment: I just copied your code from the jsfiddle into sublime text 3 and its working fine for me.If you send me your email add i can send you the files to check where yours may be going wrong. Firstly thou have you referenced to the jQuery library in a script tag before closing body tag(whether this ref is for the url or a link to file on your system). Then put the script in another file and ref this directly after?

Comment: @mattdbryce any luck?

Comment: Hi Adam, sorry for the delay in getting back to you! Work has been crazy, my email is mattdbryce@gmail.com. Thanks mate!

Comment: Just sent them now not been on in a week or so